# how to complete this regex validation

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am using jquery validator for the first time, by adding a method to validate a field against a regex. And I'm also quite new to regex :)

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        console.log(re.test(value))
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please enter only allowed characters!"
    );

$("#new_classified_id").validate({

 rules: {
     name: {
         required: true,
         minlength: 2,
         regex: /[^\uXXXX-\uXXXX]/
            }
     //,
     //comment: "required"
        }

});
});
```

I want the above to check the field against a regex in order to ONLY allow the characters in the regex range. The range isn't decided yet, hence the uXXXX. If characters are outside range, I want the message to be displayed.

Currently it is doing the exact opposite; When I enter allowed characters, the message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the '^' outside the square-brackets. You are presently excluding the characters in that range. So it shoul be:

```
   regex: /^[\uXXXX-\uXXXX]/
```